# Change margin if object is visible jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the `top` property of the object `.content` if the object `.nav-wrapper` has the property `display` set to `block`.

This is my actual (not working) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#menu").click(function(){
          $(".nav-wrapper").slideToggle("slow");

          if($(".nav-wrapper").css("display") == "block"){
               $(".content").css("top","340px");
          }
          else{
               $(".content").css("top","105px");
          }
     });
});
```

Can someone help me figuring out how to make this work?

Comment: The code looks good. But you need to set the `position:relative` for the parent and `position:absolute` for the `content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the condition **after** the animation is done.

Also, check is it is visible instead of the CSS property `display`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $(".nav-wrapper").slideToggle("slow",function(){

            if($(".nav-wrapper").is(':visible')){
                $(".content").css("top","340px");
            }
            else{
                $(".content").css("top","105px");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will make your code very procedural, But on the other hand, The default positioning `static` don't has a property called `TOP`. so you should check whether it is having any positioning rather than the `default`.

Try,

```
      if($(".nav-wrapper").is(":visible"){
           $(".content").css("top","340px");
      }
      else{
           $(".content").css("top","105px");
      }
```